# Errors while compiling irrlicht - android port (Mac OSX)

Tags: android, macos, android-ndk, irrlicht, ndk-build

I'v downloaded irrlicht android from here:

https://gitorious.org/irrlichtandroid/irrlichtandroid/source/f12c3b9743d64dc5cd61931f40e42e8ca64b40ef:

I'v tried to compile irllicht android using ndk-build, I get the following errors:

```
 In static member function 'static void irr::os::Printer::log(const c8*, irr::ELOG_LEVEL)':
error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
In static member function 'static void irr::os::Printer::log(wchar_t const*, irr::ELOG_LEVEL)':
 error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
In static member function 'static void irr::os::Printer::log(const c8*, const c8*, irr::ELOG_LEVEL)':
error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
In static member function 'static void irr::os::Printer::log(const c8*, const path&, irr::ELOG_LEVEL)':
error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/irrlicht/os.o] Error 1
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?? any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution for the issue, In project/default.propeties , I have changed:

```
target=android-4
```

to

```
target=android-18
```

And in include/IrrCompileConfig.h I have commented out:

```
//#define _IRR_COMPILE_WITH_OGLES1_
```

since I need only OpenGL ES 2. This solved the issue , `irrlichtandroid` compiled successfully using `ndk-build` , `libirrlicht.so` file generated in my project `libs` folder.

Answer (score 0):

In os.cpp(inside /jni directory), changing the code from:

```
 __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "log", message);
```

to:

```
 __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "log","%s", message);
```

solved this issue, but still an error occurs:

```
In file included from jni/importgl.cpp:55:0:
jni/importgl.h:37:22: fatal error: GLES/egl.h: No such file or directory
```

Working on it.